# Use time function with the date 2019-04-01 to add 2 hours to the time using sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, better-sqlite3

I am trying to writing sql in sqlite3 but somehow it is not passing the result .
I tried this :

```
select datetime ('2019-04-01 12:20',time('+2 hours'));
```

or

```
select time ('2019-04-01 12:20','+2 hours');
```

or

```
select date ('2019-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM',time('+2 hours'));
```

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add minutes as following

```
select DATETIME('2019-04-01 12:20', '+120 minutes') as newTime;
```

or

```
select DATETIME('2019-04-01 12:20', '+2 hours') as newTime;
```

output:

```
| newTime             |
| ------------------- |
| 2019-04-01 14:20:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `datetime()` function with modifier containing **hours** such as

```
select datetime ('2019-04-01 12:20','+2 hours');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

`SELECT time('2019-04-01','+2 hours');`